# Appending div with onkeypress event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**The main problem:** I want a inputfield to change its width based on what the user types in. This is solved. The problem comes when appending the same code several times using the onKeyPress-event with javascript append.

The first picture here shows how the code looks like before the user appends it. The inputfield is changing it's width based on the user input successfully:
[image]

The second picture here shows how the same code looks like in the "append"-function before executing:

[image]

The third picture shows how the append should look like (the code at the top) to work, while the code below shows how the code looks like after being executed by append. It seems like the `'px';'>` is missing out every time it gets appended and the input width change does not work:

[image]

The fourth picture shows where all the "bubbles" end up when being appended: 
[image]

---

**So the question** is, how can i get the appended code to act like in the first picture? Right now it's just adding the inputfields/boxes while not changing it's width when the user enters text.

Edit: the code:

```
var inv = 1;
$("#faPlus0").click(function () {
  if (inv < 10) {
     $(".bubbleBox").append("<span id='input-append' class='badge badge-secondary'><input type='text' name='invo" + inv + "'id='bubble' placeholder='Navn' onkeypress='this.style.width = ((this.value.length + 2) * 9) + 'px';'></span>");
                    inv++;
       };
    });

<span id="input-append" class="badge badge-secondary"><input type="text" name="invo0" id="bubble" placeholder="Navn" onkeypress="this.style.width = ((this.value.length + 2) * 9) + 'px';"></span>
```

Comment: Can you please put the code in the question as text and not as an image?

Comment: Sorry about that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using single quotes for the `keyup` function and also for the string inside the function. This will cause some trouble because you'll be closing the tag once you put the second quote (`+ 'px'`).

This is the generated HTML:

```
<span id='input-append' class='badge badge-secondary'><input type='text' name='invox'id='bubble' placeholder='Navn' onkeypress='this.style.width = ((this.value.length + 2) * 9) + 'px';'></span>
```

See anything wrong there? StackOverflow's code highlight will show you your mistake.

You'll have to escape those quotes to make this work. My recommendation would be to use this:

```
.append("... onkeypress=\"this.style.width = ((this.value.length + 2) * 9) + 'px';\"> ...
```

Also, add a space before the `id` part.

Comment: Oh my, this worked like a charm. Quite a newbie on javascript, so thanks for the help! I'll accept the answer as soon as I can.